# What is the etymology of the term space-time?

Tags: physics, terminology

I'm looking for the earliest references to the word *space-time* (in the modern sense), in any language.
The first references would likely be in German, as *Raum-Zeit* or *Raumzeit*.

Of course, H. Minkowski is credited as the originator of the idea. I found the following references to Minkowski's work in [Pauli's Theory of Relativity](https://archive.org/details/theoryofrelativi00paul/page/20/mode/2up?view=theater):

1. "*Das Relativitätsprinzip*", published twice (lecture 1907-11-05):

- Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung (Jber. dtsch.
  Mat. Ver.), 24 (1915) 372
- Annalen der Physik (Ann. Phys., Lpz.), 47
  (1915) 927

2. "*Die Grundgleichungen für die elektromagnetischen Vorgänge in bewegten Köpern*", published twice:

- Nachrichten von der Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Göttingen
  (Nachr. Ges. Wiss. Göttingen) (1908) 53
- Mathematische Annalen (Math. Ann.), 68 (1910) 472

3. *Raum und Zeit*, published twice (lecture 1908-09-21):

- Physikalische Zeitschrift (Phys. Z.), 10 (1909) 104
- Das Relativitätsprinzip (Leipzig 1913) - English translation [here](https://archive.org/details/principleofrelat00lore/page/74/mode/2up?view=theater). **Here he uses *die Welt* ('the world') instead of *Raum-Zeit* or *Raumzeit* (space-time)**.

I have only been able to find the text of number 3, in English translation.

Two questions:

- Is there any online access to these old German publications?
- Does anyone know of any early references to publications
  containing the word *Raum-Zeit* or *space-time* in the text?

Comment: Here is the [1910 version](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01455871) of Minkowski's  paper *Die Grundgleichungen für die elektromagnetischen Vorgänge in bewegten Körpern* with *Raum-Zeit* all over it.  Additional information: *Abgedruckt aus den Nachrichten der Kgl. Ges. d. Wiss. zu Göttingen, Math.-phys. Kl., Sitzung vom 21. Dezember 1907*, i.e. the source is from 1907. Several of these papers are translated in Space and Time
Minkowski's Papers on Relativity, some pages are visible in [Google books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Space_and_Time/Q0CDAgAAQBAJ?hl=en).

Comment: Here is the [1908 version](https://eudml.org/doc/58707) of the same paper, also with *Raum-Zeit*.

Answer (score 7):

The *Math. Ann.* paper is [here](https://archive.org/details/sim_mathematische-annalen_1910_68/page/472/mode/2up?q=minkowski&view=theater).

**Minkowski uses the term *Raum-Zeit* in this paper, not *Welt*.**

Examples of terms used in the paper:

- Raum-Zeit-Linien - lines
- Raum-Zeit-Vektoren - vectors
- Raum-Zeit-Matrix
- Raum-Zeit-Sichel  - ??
- Raum-Zeit-NullPunkte - origin event
- Raum-Zeitpunkte - point (event)

The *Ann. Phys.* paper is [here](https://archive.org/details/sim_annalen-der-physik_1915_47_15/page/926/mode/2up?view=theater). I see no use made of the term *Raum-Zeit* in this paper.

In summary, the earliest paper that I've seen that makes repeated use of *Raum-Zeit* is this paper (1910):

[Mathematische Annalen (Math. Ann.), 68 (1910) 472](https://archive.org/details/sim_mathematische-annalen_1910_68/page/472/mode/2up?q=minkowski&view=theater)

which is apparently a reprint of an earlier paper (1908; thank you @Conifold for the link):
[Nachrichten von der Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Göttingen (Nachr. Ges. Wiss. Göttingen) (1908) 5](https://eudml.org/doc/58707)

Some results from Google Books Search for "raumzeit" from 1905-01-10 to 1915-12-31:

H. Minkowski, *Raum und Zeit*,
Physikalische Zeitschrift, Vol 10, No. 3, p107 (1909-02-01).
*Raum-Zeit-NullPunkte* is the only occurrence. This doesn't seem to appear in the English translation.

Gunnar Nordström, *Zur Elektrodynamik Minkowskis*,
Physikalische Zeitschrift, Vol 10, No. 20 (1909-10-15).
*Raum-Zeit-Bezugssystemen* (frame of reference) is the only occurrence.

A. Einstein,  *Über die Entwicklung unserer Anschauungen über das Wesen und die Konstitution der Strahlung.*, Physikalische Zeitschrift, Vol 10, No. 22, p820 (1909-11-10).
*Raum-Zeit-Koordinaten* is the only occurrence.

Comment: A possible translation of _Raum-Zeit-Sichel_ may be "space-time crescent"; on an English list of [geometric shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_two-dimensional_geometric_shapes), the term "crescent" is mentioned.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen The word  [scythe](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/raum-zeit-sichel) might be implied. In that case, it might refer to a slice of space-time - that is, a surface "cut through" space-time. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a reference from 1906 (and below [in an update] from 1896).

"THE TEACHING OF MECHANICS BY EXPERIMENT"
C.E. ASHFORD

included in "The Teaching of Elementary Mechanics" by John Perry, 1906

and in

 The School World, p.335-339.

At the bottom of page 337
https://archive.org/details/schoolworld06unkngoog/page/336/mode/2up

> The diagram (Fig.2) shows one of the ordinary trolleys on its plane.
> With this a boy can produce and measure uniform velocity and acceleration.
> Every experiment with a trolley provides him with a space-time diagram ready made
> ...
> and he can plot his velocity-time and acceleration-time curves from it.

[image]

---

update

Here's an 1896 reference

"Experimental determination of the motion of projectiles inside the bore of a gun with the polarizing photo-chronograph" by Crehore, Albert and Squier, George, p. 348

https://archive.org/details/1896Experimental_photo_chronograph-BP34-6/page/348/mode/2up

> The pressure which corresponds to the constant acceleration
>
> ...
> This value, which is the probable pressure along the part of the bore where the parabola applies, it will be seen might have been much greater near the seat of the projectile without making very much change in the space-time or velocity-space curves.
>
> ...
> The parabola in this case representing the space-time curve has its origin to the left of the vertical axis instead of upon it as in the previous case. The true space-time curve must manifestly pass through the origin as the time is counted from the instant when the projectile started.
>
> ...
> The points on the velocity-time curve II are obtained by erecting ordinates equal to the tangent of inclination to the space-time curve I.

[image]

Comment: That's interesting.  So the term in the English speaking world, at least, pre-dates the ideas of Minkowski. Of course, the meaning of the term space-time, for these references, isn't quite the same as Minkowski's idea.

Comment: @John Minkowski was of course thinking about the space-time as a geometric space with its noneuclidean metric with signature +---. These authors were thinking about cartesian graphs, without realizing [from our hindsight] that these position-vs-time graphs are also "Galilean spacetimes" with a pair of degenerate noneuclidean metrics with signatures +000 and 0+++. (Euclidean, Galilean, and Minkowski geometries are specific types of the Cayley-Klein geometries.)

Comment: Well... as far as I can tell, "space-time" here is simply a short-hand notation for "a graph with a spatial co-ordinate on one axis and time on the other" - i.e. how any formula $f(t)=...$ would be graphed in school. All fine and well if looking simply for any occurrence of the two words in close proximity, but not semantically related to what OP seems to ask for (he mentions "in the modern sense")...

Comment: @AnoE  Yes, from my comment before yours,  I understood that intent of "in the modern sense" from the original question here (and in the attempted question in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759941/who-was-the-first-to-publish-the-term-spacetime ). It would be interesting if its use, in Minkowski's precise sense as a spacetime manifold for special relativity, pre-dated his "Space and Time" paper. But it is interesting to see the term in use before Minkowski, some closer to Minkowski's use and others quite distant from it.

Answer (score 4):

Using a search on Google Books ( https://books.google.com/ ) for "Raumzeit" (no hyphen, but include the quotes in the search), restricted to 19th century (an option of Tools, in the upper right),
here are some uses of "Raumzeit".

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22raumzeit%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899

I'll just include screenshots...

*Sorry I can't easily transcribe and proofread the German text.

I'll leave it to others to interpret the use of the term in these contexts.*

---

(1861) Friedrich Gottlob Röber
"Elementar-Beiträge zu Bestimmung des Naturgesetzes der Gestaltung und des Widerstandes, und Anwendung dieser Beiträge auf Natur und alte Kunstgestaltung"

p15:
[image]

p18-19:
[image]

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

(1803) Biblia sacra oder die heilige Schrift des alten und neuen Testamentes, Volume 1

p 299 (footnote):
[image]

---

By changing the range to 1700-1800, this came up... presumably an earlier version of the 1803 one.

(1786)
“Die” heilige Schrift des alten (und neuen) Testamentes ... neuerdings übers. von Heinrich Braun -  Christian Friedrich Wappler, 1786

p.299
[image]

Comment: As you mention you can't really transcribe the text: the first is a, to me, very weird use of Raumzeit/Zeitraum, almost like the terms were defined from scratch for some mathematical construction in that book. I have never heard or seen anything like it - it does not seem to have left a mark on physics or maths. The second describes the "Sabbatjahr" or "sabbatical" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatical, and here also, at least in modern German, the term "Raumzeit" is not used in any context of this, as far as I know (in Germany, we simply say "Sabbatical" oder "Auszeit", not "Raumzeit").

Comment: "Zeitraum", while literally "time-space" in modern German simply means "time interval" and has no connotation with "space" at all, neither in everyday language nor physics.

Comment: I was not aware that "Raumzeit" was used as a synonym for "Sabbatjahr" - a nice find! But this usage must have been obsolete for quite a while. The authoritative [German dictionary](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB#1) by the Grimm brothers from 1854 does list "Sabbatjahr" but not "Raumzeit". If I had to speculate on the etymology, I'd say "Raumzeit" in this old agricultural sense refers to a time ("Zeit") where you leave room ("Raum") for anything to grow on the fields (no sowing and harvesting as stated in the footnotes of the bible texts).

Answer (score 3):

Here are 1898 references that use "**l'espace-temps**"

(My goal in these searches is to find in publications 
the term "spacetime" or "space-time",
regardless of Minkowski's specific idea of the spacetime manifold with metric-signature isomorphic to +--- .

From my comment (in response to another comment) in my first answer,
it would be interesting if its use, in Minkowski's precise sense as a spacetime manifold for special relativity, pre-dated his "Space and Time" paper. But it is interesting to see the term in use before Minkowski, some closer to Minkowski's use and others quite distant from it. )

I found these using my Google Books search method.

---

"L'intuition motrice"
Georges Dubreuque
Revue Philosophique de la France Et de l'Etranger 46:253 - 292 (1898),
p. 262

(copy-paste of the pdf... I didn't proofread it.  You could try to paste it into Google Translate. I bolded the term.)

> La vue est , de tous les appareils de perception , celui qui fournit à la connaissance les matériaux les mieux élaborés ; la perception optique procède par ensembles , et non comme la perception auditive par fragments successifs ; la compréhension visuelle a lieu sans efforts ; elle n'est pas , comme il arrive parfois pour la compré hension auditive , un moment distinct de la sensation brute . Quelle que puisse être à cet égard la supériorité du sens visuel , la géomé trie ne l'utilise pas ; elle ne raisonne pas sur des « perceptions mas sives » . Les figures géométriques sont obtenues par génération , ce qui signifie qu'elles vont du détail à l'ensemble , et non , comme pour les perceptions visuelles ordinaires , de l'ensemble au détail . La cons truction géométrique , aussi bien que la déduction , est « le terme d'un mouvement » ; la ligne est engendrée par le mouvement d'un point , la surface par le mouvement d'une ligne , le volume par le mouvement d'une surface . La notion fondamentale de la géométrie n'est donc pas proprement l'espace , mais le mouvement dans l'espace , autrement dit **l'espace - temps** ; les figures sont des mouve ments qu'on étudie sous un aspect particulier et sans avoir égard aux vitesses ni aux accélérations ; l'élimination de la variable temps n'est en quelque sorte que virtuelle , et quelques mathématiciens ont trouvé avantage à l'y réintroduire , en traitant la géométrie comme une branche de la cinématique .

[image]

---

La logique sociale
Gabriel de Tarde
F. Alcan (ed), 1898

pages: 91,92,164, (contents)463

(copy-paste of the pdf... I didn't proofread it.  You could try to paste it into Google Translate. I bolded the term.)

p.91

> ...Ce moyen d'échange est fourni , en psychologie individuelle , par ces deui entités singulières : l'espace et le temps , que j'aimerais mieux désigner en un seul mot , **l'Espace - Temps** , tellement leur lien est intime , et en psy chologie sociale , par cette autre entité non moins étrange , non moins féconde en idolâtries ou en illusions réalistes : la langue , qui , comme nous le verrons , a deux faces bien distinctes . Il y a d'ailleurs à remarquer , disons - le tout de suite , que ces entités , **l'Espace - Temps** et la langue , quoique étant la condition du déve loppement de ces réalités : le Monde et Dieu , ont dû se déve lopper parallèlement à celles - ci et se sont formées peut - être de leurs débris lentement accumulés ; car toute notion a commencé par être un jugement , et tout moyen par être un but .
> [image: p91]

p92

> Ainsi , je me garde de confondre les fonctions et les catégories . Le juge ment et la volonté , la religion et la politique , sont des fonctions ; mais la Matière - Force ainsi que **l'Espace - Temps** , la Divinité ainsi que la Langue sont des catégories . Ce sont là des catégo ries logiques , c'est - à - dire n'ayant trait qu'aux fonctions intellec tuelles du Jugement et de la Religion . Mais il y a aussi des catégories ou demi - catégories téléologiques , qui répondent aux fonctions pratiques de la volonté et du gouvernement . L'agréable et le douloureux sont l'un poursuivi , l'autre évité par le vouloir de l'individu primitif comme des choses qui existent en dehors de lui , et qu'il incarne dans les objets matériels de ses percep tions : de même , le bien et le mal sont poursuivis ou évités par le devoir de l'homme social , comme des réalités idéales ou des idéalités réelles qu'il cherche à fixer et qu'il fixe en effet en les incorporant dans les objets divins de son adoration . Il y a donc , en tout , pour l'esprit individuel , les catégories suivantes , logiques ou téléologiques : la Matière - Force , **l'Espace - Temps** , le Plaisir et a Douleur ; et pour l'esprit social : la Divinité , la Langue , le Bien
> [image]

p164

> Le mouvement n'est que la traduction symbolique de l'évolution . Nous ne pouvons nous faire de celle - ci une idée moins large que de celui - là . Et , puisque nous voyons le champ immense de **l'Espace - Temps** ouvert à la diversité infinie , à la merveilleuse multiformité des mouve ments , sans que cette apparente liberté nuise en rien à leur détermination rigoureuse , à la stricte application des lois méca niques , - dont **l'Espace - Temps** est , pour ainsi dire , la notion intégrale , l'applicabilité totale , nous devons nous dire à priori , et l'observation des faits semble nous donner pleinement raison , que les lois de la logique , cette mécanique interne , ouvrent un débouché non moins vaste à l'inépuisable variété des évolutions soit vivantes , soit psychologiques et sociales . Il y a une logique vitale ( laquelle nous apparaît surtout sous son aspect téléologique ) , comme il y a une logique mentale et sociale . Et , si **l'Espace - Temps** est l'applicabilité totale de la mécanique , on peut dire aussi bien que la Vie , sorte d'espace des dévelop pements biologiques , est l'applicabilité totale de la logique vivante , et que l'Esprit , sorte d'espace aussi des développements psychologiques et sociaux , est l'applicabilité totale de la logique individuelle et sociale .
> [image]

Comment: I agree. It's interesting and useful to see all uses of the term, in different contexts.